# Extracting a number from a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, time, dialogflow-es, google-home

I believe very similar questions were asked, however, the provided answers/examples are not really applicable to my question. Well, at least not to the extent of my knowledge - I'm not a Javascript connoisseur, so pardon me for that.

Working with a Google Home device, I have the user say how much time he would like to have breakfast. He can answer in minutes, which is saved into a variable the_breakfast_minutes. How can I then extract the number from, for example, these strings using JS:

- 20 minutes
- 5 minutes

etc.

Gladly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can get the number as a string like this:

```
minutes_string = the_breakfast_minutes.split(" ")[0]
```

Then, you can convert it to a number (if you need to) like this:

```
minutes_number = parseInt(minutes_string)
```

Here's a snippet with a working example:

```js
const the_breakfast_minutes = "20 minutes"
const minutes_string = the_breakfast_minutes.split(" ")[0]
const minutes_number = parseInt(minutes_string)

console.log(minutes_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question generally: you can use `match(regular expression)`.

```js
const str = "minu20tes"
const number = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0])
```

That is assuming the number to extract is a positive integer.
If needed, `/[\+\-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[Ee][\+\-]?\d+)?/` will also include negative, decimals and exponents.